# Remove the last number in a number in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to get a number, knock the last number off and then return it as a number

i.e. given the number 12345, return 1234

is this the best way to do it:

```
let x = 12345
const y = x.toString().split('').slice(0, -1).join('')
const newNum = Number(y)
```

also is there a way to not do the const `newNum` and then just convert it back to a number in the string above?

Comment: You could just divide the number by 10 and then call `Math.floor()`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's another way to do it

```js
console.log(
    Math.floor(12345 / 10) // -> 1234
)
```

Comment: I like this the best

Comment: @zfrisch It might, but given how simple the question is, I think it might be a bit too complicated to understand.

Comment: It's not complicated? `Math.floor(12345 / 10)` or `12345 / 10 | 0` will end up with the same result. If someone doesn't understand that, they can look into it. That's how you learn about these things.

Comment: @zfrisch I agree, that is how you learn how to do these things, however, I think it is more important understand how the things you are doing *work*, than just doing it. Since the OP apparently didn't know about `Math.floor(12345 / 10)`, I thought it would be a bit overkill to introduce them to how bitwise operators work and how they convert floating point numbers to signed 32-bit integers . Also, because of that, it won't always give you the same result, it only works upto 2^31 − 1.

Comment: @ARatherLongName I'm aware, but I was offering additional information, not an alternative to your answer.

Comment: This solution does not seem to work for the following input: `Math.floor(11111111111111111111111111111101 / 10)`. The result becomes: `1.1111111111111112e+30`

Answer (score 5):

Easy:

```js
console.log(12345 / 10 ^ 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using parseInt() to convert back to number, and substring to get the entire number minus the last digit

```
return parseInt(x.toString().substring(0, x.toString().length - 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could refactor the code to this

```js
let x = 12345
const newNum = Number(x.toString().slice(0, -1))
console.log(newNum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the number into brackets `()` to use `.slice()`

```js
let x = 12345
const newNum = (x).toString().slice(0, -1)
console.log(newNum)
console.log(newNum * 1000)
```

Comment: and now it's a string and not a number